# flask and tailwind - changes in master.css are not used when rendered

Tags: flask, tailwind-css

I wanted to change my color scheme and therefore added custom colors to tailwind in the tailwindconfig file, but although in can find them in the master.css after building the css, the flask dev server doesnt not use the new colors but the old ones.
I looked if I have connected the wrong stylesheet but I actually have connected the right one.

help would very much appreciated. Thank you already!

tailwind.config.js

```
    purge: [],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                "mont": "montserrat"
            },
            colors: {
                "primary": "#595b83",
                "secondary": "#f4abc4",
                "third": "#f4abc4",
                "fourth": "#060930"
            }
        },
    },
    variants: {},
    plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that your browser uses the cache, and you need to clear the cache before refreshing the page.
If you are using Google Chrome, press the `ctrl+shift+delete` key combination to enter the clear cache page.

Comment: can't believe that was the problem actually, but you are right!